# Can hyperthread be enabled

Tags: hp-ux, hyperthreading

I would like to know if hyperthread can be enabled on my operating system or not? I am using HP-UX Itanium, below is truncated output of machinfo

```
 Intel(R)  Itanium(R)  Processor 9560 (2.53 GHz, 32 MB)
   8 cores, 16 logical processors per socket
   6.38 GT/s QPI, CPU version D0
          Active processor count:
          1 socket
          8 cores (8 per socket)
          8 logical processors (8 per socket)
          LCPU attribute is disabled
```

OS Info is as below:

```
Release:   HP-UX B.11.31
```

Comment: Don't know if this applies to your Poulson CPU, but have a look at [Enable HyperThreading in HP-UX V3](https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/Enable-HyperThreading-in-HP-UX-V3/td-p/5284126#.XHKFV-hKhPY) and [HT ON/OFF - HP-UX Virtual Partitions Admin's Guide](https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/T1335-90098/ch06s25.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a loooong time, but I think you want

```
    setboot -m on
```

according to [this hp support doc](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01691020).

Comment: Thank you for your answer however my question is whether hyperthreading can be enabled on this server or not. Until now, its running on single thread, I want to request for enabling that however I am not sure whether it will be supported on HP-UX in my version or not.

Comment: Yes, it should be able if your "HP-UX B.11.31" is "HP-UX 11i v3 (11.31)". See both links in my comment.

Comment: I think this will work for you. HPs manual site (the link in the doc I linked to) seems to be down, here is a mirror: https://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/5991-1247B/ch07s08.html I think the instructions are server agnostic. Your cpu is itanium, albe it a different arch. I think they are the same (e.g. I used to maintain one years back).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not into Operating system side; so, not very much aware of them.